# How to resolve the Composer dependencies conflicts (symfony)?

Tags: php, symfony, flexbox, composer-php, symfony6

I'm writing a PHP application based on Symfony v6. Now I want to upgrade Symfony to the ^v6.3

```
composer require symfony/symfony:^6.3
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/symfony
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/cache 6.2.*, found symfony/cache[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.13] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/config 6.2.*, found symfony/config[v6.2.0, v6.2.5, v6.2.7, v6.2.13] but the package is fixed to v6.3.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/console 6.2.*, found symfony/console[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.13] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 4
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/web-profiler-bundle 6.2.*, found symfony/web-profiler-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.13] but the package is fixed to v6.3.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 5
    - projet 2.46.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony v6.3.4.
    - projet 2.46.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony v6.3.3.
    - projet 2.46.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony v6.3.2.
    - projet 2.46.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony v6.3.1.
    - projet 2.46.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony v6.3.0.
    - projet is present at version 2.46.3 and cannot be modified by Composer
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/symfony ^6.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v6.3.0, ..., v6.3.4].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.``your text``
```

```
composer require --update-with-all-dependencies symfony/framework-bundle:^6.3
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/framework-bundle --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "6.2.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/config 6.2.*, found symfony/config[v6.2.0, v6.2.5, v6.2.7, v6.2.13] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/console 6.2.*, found symfony/console[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.13] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/dependency-injection ^6.2, found symfony/dependency-injection[v6.2.0, ..., v6.3.4] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 4
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/web-profiler-bundle 6.2.*, found symfony/web-profiler-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.13] but the package is fixed to v6.3.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 5
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle is locked to version 2.10.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.10.2 requires symfony/config ^5.4 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.26, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 6
    - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle is locked to version 3.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 3.5.0 requires symfony/config ^4.4|^5.3|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.3.0, ..., v5.4.26, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 7
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle is locked to version v3.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v3.2.1 requires symfony/config ^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.26, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 8
    - jms/serializer-bundle is locked to version 5.3.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - jms/serializer-bundle 5.3.1 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^3.4 || ^4.0 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/dependency-injection[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.49, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.28, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.4] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 9
    - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle is locked to version v2.19.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle v2.19.1 requires symfony/config ^4.4|^5.3|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.3.0, ..., v5.4.26, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 10
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle is locked to version v6.2.10 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle v6.2.10 requires symfony/config ^4.4|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.26, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 11
    - symfony/monolog-bundle is locked to version v3.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/monolog-bundle v3.8.0 requires symfony/config ~4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.26, v6.0.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 12
    - symfony/maker-bundle is locked to version v1.51.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.51.1 requires symfony/config ^6.3|^7.0 -> found symfony/config[v6.3.0, v6.3.2] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.2.*).
  Problem 13
    - symfony/twig-bundle is locked to version v6.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/twig-bundle v6.3.0 requires symfony/config ^6.1 -> found symfony/config[v6.1.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 14
    - symfony/framework-bundle[v6.3.0, ..., v6.3.4] require symfony/config ^6.1 -> found symfony/config[v6.1.0, ..., v6.3.2] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/framework-bundle ^6.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v6.3.0, v6.3.1, v6.3.2, v6.3.4].




Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "projet",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.46.3",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.3",
        "christian-riesen/otp": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.8",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.1.5",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^5.3",
        "lesstif/php-jira-rest-client": "^2.0",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.19",
        "psr/cache": "3.0",
        "psr/log": "^1.1.4",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^6.2",
        "symfony/cache": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/config": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^6.2",
        "symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^2.5",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^5.3",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.17",
        "symfony/mime": "^6.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.8.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^2.14"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.48.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^6.0",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.2.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": [
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "branch-alias": null,
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your composer json file as well

Comment: Did this really run under an earlier version of Symfony 6.x?  The FOS user bundle makes me very suspicious.  You can try the suggestions in the answer.  Might be easier to just create a fresh Symfony app and then add the various third party bundles.  Then move the new composer.json to your app. But again some of your dependencies seem outdated.

Comment: It looks like the code you're using is version 2.46 which makes me think that this is software that is in production. Is this software for your company or is this some software that you're using? If the version is really 2.46 and not some arbitrary number, that what Cerad says is probably ill-advised. However, if this isn't really production software, then I would agree and start fresh! If this is code that you've purchased/using from elsewhere, contact the vendor/support. Production code already 2.46 in version is probably something that is not trivial to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `composer require symfony/symfony:^6.3`

Since the `composer.json` contains every dependency (this is a good practice) but not `symfony/symfony`, this command fails because `symfony/symfony` will replace all the dependencies.

Instead, we can:

- upgrade every Symfony dependency from 6.2 to 6.3
- upgrade `symfony/dotenv` to 6.3 (you used `5.3`)
- upgrade `symfony/runtime` to 6.3 (you used `5.4`)
- keep the current versions for the Symfony packages that aren't components: `symfony/deprecation-contracts`, `symfony/flex`, etc.

`composer install` works with these dependencies:

```
{
    "name": "projet/projet",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.46.3",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.3",
        "christian-riesen/otp": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.8",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.1.5",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^5.3",
        "lesstif/php-jira-rest-client": "^2.0",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.19",
        "psr/cache": "3.0",
        "psr/log": "^1.1.4",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^6.3",
        "symfony/cache": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/config": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^6.3",
        "symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^2.5",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^6.3",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.17",
        "symfony/mime": "^6.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.8.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^2.14"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.48.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^6.0",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.3.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": [
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "branch-alias": null,
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To perform a minor version update (6.2 to 6.3) it requires more than simply `composer require symfony/symfomy:~6.3`

You'll want to review the detailed process on the official Symfony Framework Website: [Upgrading a Minor Version](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html).

**In summary:**

1. Manually update your composer.json file to replace 6.2 with 6.3  (looks like you have some other Symfony components at 5.4 which are a major upgrade.
2. Then run `composer update "symfony/*" --with-all-dependencies`
3. Upgrade other packages as necessary
4. Nothing should have broken in your code between 6.2 and 6.3, however other packages you use might have broken, so you might need to fix them.
5. Consider upgrading your recipes.

With regards to your components at v5.4, you'll need to follow the [Major Version Upgrade](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html). This will be more involved.

Also looking ahead, now would be a good time, once you've completed everything above, to start working on any code deprecations, because when the next major version comes along you'll be ahead of the curve.